# Running nx target only if file doesn't exist

Tags: nrwl-nx

I have a project which has a `build` step, however, I need to make sure that the file `firebase.config.json` exists before running the `build` command.

With that, I have two NPM scripts:

```json
// package.json
{
  ...,
  "nx": {
    "targets": {
      "prepare": {
        "outputs": ["firebase.config.json"]
      },
      "build": {
        "outputs": ["dist"],
        "dependsOn": [
          {
            "target": "prepare",
            "projects": "self"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "firebase apps:sdkconfig web $FIREBASE_APP_ID_SHOP --json | jq .result.sdkConfig > firebase.config.json",
    "build": "VITE_FIREBASE_CONFIG=$(cat ./firebase.config.json) vite build",
  },
  ...
}
```

So with the above, every time I run `nx build app` it will first run `prepare` and build the `firebase.config.json` file.

However, every time I make a change to any of the source files inside my project, `prepare` re-runs even though the `firebase.config.json` is already present.

Is it possible for nx to only run a target if the file declared under `outputs` is not present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a bash environment you can modify your prepare script to be the following (note the original command has been shortened with ellipses for readability).

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts":{
    "prepare": "CONFIG=firebase.config.json; [ -f \"$CONFIG\" ] || firebase apps:sdkconfig ... | jq ... > \"$CONFIG\""
  }
}
```

The above prepare script *will still run*, but it should not spend any time reproducing the configuration file if it already exists.

`CONFIG=firebase.config.json` is just putting our file in a bash environment variable so we can use it in multiple places (helps prevent typos). `[ -f "$CONFIG" ]` will return true if `$CONFIG` holds a filename which corresponds to an existing file. If it returns true, it will short-circuit the `||` (OR) command.

If you want further verification of this technique, you can test this concept at the terminal with the command `[ -f somefile.txt ] || echo "File does not exist"`. If `somefile.txt` does *not* exist, then the `echo` *will* run. If the file *does* exist, then the `echo` will *not* run.

A slightly-related side-note: while you clearly can do this all in the `package.json` configuration, if your nx workspace is going to grow to include other libraries or applications, I highly recommend splitting up all your workspace configuration into the default nx configuration files: `nx.json`, `workspace.json`, and the per-project `project.json` files for the sake of readability/maintainability.

Best of luck!